# cbind values to sublists in R

Tags: r, list, cbind

I have two matrices in a list:

```
colList <- list()
colList[["V1"]] <- as.matrix(c("asd", "asd", "asd"))
colList[["V2"]] <- as.matrix(c("das", "das", "das"))
```

And I want to cbind the values of a data.frame `value.frame$keyID` to each sublist. The first value (2000) to the first sublist, the second value (3000) to the second sublist.

Here the value.frame:

```
value.frame <- data.frame(keyID =c("2000", "3000"))
```

The result should look like this:

```
colList <- list()
colList[["V1"]] <-  matrix(c("asd", "asd", "asd", 2000, 2000, 2000), 
                                nrow=3, 
                                ncol=2)

colList[["V2"]] <-  matrix(c("das", "das", "das", 3000, 3000, 3000), 
                               nrow=3, 
                               ncol=2)
```

I tried it with the following code, but the result is not the desired one. Hope someone can help me.

```
mapply( cbind, colList, paste(value.frame[,1]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lapply` and `seq_along`

```
nms <- names(colList)
colList <- lapply(seq_along(colList), x=colList,
   y=as.character(value.frame$keyID), function(j, x, y) {
  cbind(x[[j]], y[j])
})

names(colList) <- nms
colList[["V1"]]
     [,1]  [,2]  
[1,] "asd" "2000"
[2,] "asd" "2000"
[3,] "asd" "2000"

colList[["V2"]] 
     [,1]  [,2]  
[1,] "das" "3000"
[2,] "das" "3000"
[3,] "das" "3000"
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `mapply` using the option `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`

```
mapply(cbind, colList, as.character(value.frame$keyID), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
#$V1
#     [,1]  [,2]  
#[1,] "asd" "2000"
#[2,] "asd" "2000"
#[3,] "asd" "2000"

#$V2
#     [,1]  [,2]  
#[1,] "das" "3000"
#[2,] "das" "3000"
#[3,] "das" "3000"
```

Or using `Map` which is a wrapper for `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`

```
Map(cbind, colList, as.character(value.frame$keyID))
```